# Decoding and connetting a keyboard PCB

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, raspberry-pi, driver, keyboard

I want to build a laptop from a raspberry-pi and an old "toy laptop" (and new components), the spare toy laptop I have is a [Oregon Scientific Batman BL31T](https://picclick.it/Oregon-Scientific-Batman-Dark-Knight-PowerWing-Learning-Computer-133754217274.html). I would like to use its case and keyboard and buy a raspberry, a power bank and new screen, the problem is the keyboard.
The keyboard is actually a custom PCB with several wires connected to what I think is the motherboard, I need to understand if it's possible to connect the keyboard to a raspberry-pi (or Arduino or whatever) and "decode" each key so that I can configure it as a normal keyboard.

if this is not possible, can I buy some keyboard matrix/keyboard PCB to use the original keyboard buttons? (I would like to preserve them).

I'm sorry, I'm missing for sure some technical terms since I'm not so experienced in this field, I tried to make the description clear; here are some photos attached (1-2: Keyboard, 3: Motherboard).

[image: Keyboard PCB (and a small controller attached to the keyboard)]
[image: Keyboard PCB - better circuit view]
[image: Motherboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to reverse engineer keyboard matricies like these.

You'll need to scrap the existing controller and replace it with another controller, in your case I'd cut the wires at the controller end not the keyboard end as that will make it easier to connect to another circuit.

Part of the process will be working out the key connections. The matrix will be a series of row and columns, so you'll need to identify which pins are the rows, and which pins are the columns, and which key each row/column combination corresponse to.

Essentially this is a case of working out which two pins each of the keys connect to. You can do this one of two ways:

1. Trace the layout of the matrix - follow the routing (either visually or with continuity tester) to work out which pin each side of each key contact connects to.
2. For each key, press and hold the key down, then check which two wires are shorted out (it looks like a passive membrane, so shouldn't be any diodes to worry about).

You should be able to draw up a 2-D matrix (e.g. in excel, or draw a table) of rows and columns and the corresponding key when any given row/col is shorted. There are many possible arrangments for the table, it doesn't really matter how you arrange it. With a bit of luck, the wires will be neatly grouped, with rows on one end, and columns on the other.

Once the matrix is identified, you will need a controller. I did this with a laptop keyboard about 10 years ago using a commercial PS/2 keyboard controller IC. However nowadays, there is an abundance of programmable microcontrollers (e.g. ATMega32U4, MSP430, and dev kits like the Arduino Leonardo) which can present as USB HID keyboards. So implementing the controller is now quite easy. I won't go into the details as there are a great many resources for scanning row/column 2-D button matricies.

Comment: Thank you @Tom, the explanation is clear, can you recommend any resources for connecting to the Arduino? At the moment [this](https://www.instructables.com/Arduino-UnoLeonardo-Keyboard-Macro-Box/) is what I found.
Anyway is it possible to use the raspberry to do the work that the Arduino does? Or there exist a more "minimal approach"? I mean, I know that an Arduino is powerful (correct me, if there simpler/smaller Arduinos!), I don't want to use an Arduino to make something a simpler controller can do, although I know it may be more difficult, e.g. PS/2 keyboard controller IC you cited before

Comment: @Fral I think the IC I used has long since been discontinued - nowadays the functionality is so easy to acheive in cheap MCUs that there probably isn't enough of a market for them. There are a few app notes out there, for example [this one](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa514/slaa514.pdf) from TI that show how to build a keyboard using an MCU.

Comment: Thanks again @Tom for your precious support, I'll follow your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Connecting a keyboard with anode (+) and cathode(-)  scanning presents a close switch as a logic"0" when a key is pressed.  This requires row and column scanners to detect the cross point switch closure to null the voltage between the matrix of switches during this interval and thus decode it's function.  Since the switch is a carbon type the resistance is higher than a normal switch = 0 Ohms but easily detected compared to open circuit.

Answer (score -1):

ah well its a blob chip. From what I can see i would investigate the 14 pin flat pack surface mount chip, see if it is connected to the keyboard and if you can just directly rout it to the pi.

If it does all the keyboard handling then that makes your life easier.So like press keys and see what the chip gives out and doing a map for key press. (maybe you could extend the functionality for unused pins or pin combinations. A closer pic of the IC would help to read the part number and maybe labeling what each wired go to could be helpful.